# Вызвать элемент структуры в Си

Tags: c, gcc

такая ситуация, к примеру у меня записано имя элемента в указатель char *name = "id"; и мне надо его вызвать ( типа: struct[0].(name) ). Подскажите как это реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В си так сделать нельзя. Но есть куча обходных маневров. Самый простой способ - создать воспомогательную функцию вида

```
void set_field(struct my_struct* st, const char* field, int value)
{
  if (strcmp(field, "id") == 0) { st->id = value; }
  else if (....) ...

}
```

Если типы значений разные - чуточку сложнее, но можно использовать `void*` и size.

Comment: Печально что нельзя, но все равно спасибо.